# Is it possible to have a method as both bound and unbound in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods, static-methods

I was curious whether Python allowed both a bound and unbound version an otherwise identically named method within a class e.g.

```
class Bounds(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method(self):
        print('I am a bound method')

    @staticmethod
    def method():
        print('I am an unbound method free of the class instance!')
```

I wish to do something like:

```
>>> b = Bounds()
>>> b.method()
I am a bound method
>>> Bounds.method()
I am an unbound method free of the class instance!
```

All I get, however, is the last defined method within the class for both versions.

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks!

## EDIT

For those interested in both bound and unbound usage (despite its obfuscating the API), it can be achieved with a few dirty hacks using a base class and lambda's in the constructor of the derived class:

```
class _Bounds(object):
    def method(self, msg="Can you free me?"):
        print('I am a bound method: "{}"'.format(msg))

class Bounds(_Bounds):
    @staticmethod
    def method():
        print('I'm free from the shackles of the class instance!')

    def __init__(self):
      self.method = lambda **kw: _Bounds(self, **kw)
      # do stuff
```

Then test with:

```
>>> Bounds().method()
I am a bound method: Can you free me?
>>> Bounds.method()
I'm free from the shackles of the class instance!
```

Comment: You'd have to use a special descriptor object to handle the two contexts differently. I duped you to a question where I used the same technique to bind to either the class or the instance.

Comment: I would, however, strongly advice you to rethink your API and avoid such confusing overloading of meaning.

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the swift answer Martijn. Whilst I agree that it is not necessarily best practice, I was simply wondering if you could do both as a matter of academic interest. Once again the powers of Python never cease to amaze me...